# How do you process a sliding window using karafka?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-kafka, karafka

I have a stream of messages in a Kafka topic. For each message, I need to examine previous messages that occur within 10 seconds of the current message.

I assume that I can keep a buffer with the current window in my consumer. How do I reconstruct the window for the current offset if my consumer dies or gets replaced?